# No se pueden crear etiquetas nuevas desde aplicación móvil

Tags: bug, app-móvil

Hoy me encontré con esta pregunta [¿Cómo puedo iterar en Jade con distintos contenidos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3981/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-iterar-en-jade-con-distintos-contenidos)

El título es claro, el usuario tiene un problema con jade. Quise editar la pregunta para agregar la etiqueta que parece ser nueva y obtuve el siguiente resultado

[image]

Al no existir la etiqueta, simplemente no puedo crearla. Realicé esto desde mi iPhone y desde mi dispositivo android sin resultados. Desde la aplicación web esto se puede realizar sin problemas.

¿Será posible agregar esta función en la aplicación móvil?

Comment: Luiggi, el problema solo ocurre en SOes? Es decir, puedes crear etiqueta desde otro sitio por ejemplo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Correcto, por ahora no es posible crear etiquetas desde la aplicación móvil.

Comment: Gracias por la notificacion JuanM. Sabes si hay planes para agregar dicha funcionalidad en las aplicaciones moviles?